# Mongoose: Change 2dsphere index version

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to upload my database to the heroku mongodbLab addon. My MongoDB version is 3.2.4 and my servers is 3.0.9. Mongoose is 4.4.6. However, when I run the command `$ mongorestore -h myhostname -d mydatabase -u username -p password ~/tmp/mongodump/Loc8r` to push the db to heroku I get the error:

```
building a list of collections to restore from /Users/user/tmp/mongodump/Loc8r dir
reading metadata for database.locations from /Users/user/tmp/mongodump/Loc8r/locations.metadata.json
restoring database.locations from /Users/user/tmp/mongodump/Loc8r/locations.bson
restoring indexes for collection database.locations from metadata
Failed: database.locations: error creating indexes for database.locations: createIndex error: exception: unsupported geo index version { 2dsphereIndexVersion : 2dsphereIndexVersion: 3 }, only support versions: [1,2]
```

How can I change the 2dsphereIndexVersion in my schema?

Here's my schema file for my db:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var openingTimesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  days: {type: String, required: true},
  opening: String,
  closing: String,
  closed: {type: Boolean, required: true}
});

var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  author: String,
  rating: {type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 5},
  reviewText: String,
  createdOn: {type: Date, "default": Date.now}
});

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type:String, required: true},
  address: String,
  rating: {type: Number, "default": 0, min: 0, max: 5},
  facilities: [String],
  coords: {type: [Number], index: '2dsphere', "2dsphereIndexVersion": 2},
  openingTimes: [openingTimesSchema],
  reviews: [reviewSchema]
});

mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```

As you can see I tried to change it by adding that attribute `"2dsphereIndexVersion": 2`. However, that didn't work. Anyone know how I can change this?

-EDIT-
I'm using mongoose to create the database with the schema above. I am trying to set the `"2dsphereIndexVersion"` to 2 because it's required by my servers version of MongoDB.

Comment: what version of Mongo you use now and what version is on destination server?

Comment: I am using 3.2.4 and the destination server is using 3.0.9.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up changing the .metadata.json file to look like this:

```
{"options":{},"indexes":[{"v":1,"key":{"_id":1},"name":"_id_","ns":"Loc8r.locations"},{"v":1,"key":{"coords":"2dsphere"},"name":"coords_2dsphere","ns":"Loc8r.locations","background":true,"2dsphereIndexVersion":2}]}
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thanks! (The getting MEAN with Mongo book is great)